# how to write special character degree sign from ruby to file

Tags: ruby

I want to do like this:

```
File.open("file.txt","w+") do |f1|
  f1.write(" °C")
end
```

but it has an error because of  "°" , how can I do fix this?

Comment: Can you please add the error message and backtrace? (the code works for me in ruby 2.0)

Comment: when I load page, it show "We're sorry, but something went wrong" in browser and 'syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
                        f1.write('°')
                                    ^):'
in console.

Comment: Then the error is not the text, but a syntax error. Probably you forgot to close a parenthesis or forgot an `end`. You need to give us more of your source code to help here :)

Comment: When I write 
f1.write("C")
it has no error so I think that's because of "°".

Comment: Which ruby version do you use? When it's < 2.0, then sawa has an aswer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ruby < 2.0, then put this magic comment at the beginning of that file:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

If that does not work, then delete the file `"file.txt"` once, and try again. The file may not be compatible with the encoding.